# Redirection handling in ROKU

Tags: redirect, roku

I am trying to call an API in ROKU player using bright script. But I a getting "**response code -3**". But when I am hitting that service on Web Browser it gives the xml in response. Actually there is a redirection in the API which I am using. As I know the redirection is not handled by the ROKU OS level. So How will I come out this situation. 
Please help me and provide me any solution for that how can I handle the redirection in ROKU?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roku's roUrlTransfer does handle redirects.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation at http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roUrlEvent gives `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT` as name for the `-3` code you got from `GetResponseCode()` on the `roUrlEvent`. Try checking the string you get from `GetFailureReason()` on that same `roUrlEvent`, which should give a more detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are missing any header in http request. 
Check for accept header also.

Answer (score -2):

[Check this link how to make Get and Post request in Roku.](https://roku.home.blog/2018/12/05/how-to-make-get-and-post-a-request-in-roku-scenegraph/)

```
request = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
request.SetUrl("http://blog.roku.com/developer")
html = request.GetToString()
```